# How do I convert the Amplitude from Power/Amplitude spectral density?

Tags: experimental-physics, fourier-transform, frequency, spectroscopy, signal-processing

I've started working on PSD for seismic signals. In theory, PSD signal can be expressed in 2 ways. One in $(PSD=g^2/Hz)$ and other in $PSD=((meter/second^2)^2/Hz)$ and also ASD=(√PSD). Here $g$ is the acceleration.

More details have found in the link https://ucum.org/ucum.html#section-Special-Units-on-non-ratio-Scales

I want to find the amplitude of the spectrum in $(meter.second)^2/Hz$ from the expression of PSD. I don't clearly find a way to get the amplitude at a specific frequency in the unit of $(meter.second)^2/Hz$.
How can I get the amplitude in the unit of $(meter.second)^2/Hz$? Probably the unit of amplitude may be derived from the unit of PSD, but I've no idea how to get the amplitude in the above unit?

## OR

Without correlating the above PSD/ASD, what is the process to express amplitude (e.g. seismic signals) in terms of $(meter.second)^2/Hz$?

## Answer (Confused)

So far I understand, one can find the amplitude from the $PSD$ in sunch a way that amplitude, $A = √PSD * scaling_factor$. $scaling_factor= 2/(fs*S)$ depends on the size of window and the sampling frequency of the signal (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/what-should-be-the-correct-scaling-for-psd-calculation-using-tt-fft/32205#32205). Am I correct?

$S$ - sum of squared samples of window function
$f_s$ - sampling frequency
Scaling coefficient $2$ takes into account removal of energy at negative frequencies (we drop this side of PSD).

Can anyone have any explanations?

Comment: Minor comment: $PSD=ASD^2$, not $\sqrt{ASD}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I understand, one can find the amplitude from the $PSD$ in sunch a way that amplitude, $A = √PSD * scaling factor$. $scaling factor= 2/(fs*S)$ depends on the size of window and the sampling frequency of the signal (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/what-should-be-the-correct-scaling-for-psd-calculation-using-tt-fft/32205#32205).
Am I correct? If I go wrong, I appreciate if anyone find me wrong.

$S$ - sum of squared samples of window function,

$f_s$ - sampling frequency

Scaling coefficient $2$ takes into account removal of energy at negative frequencies (we drop this side of PSD).

## Now the unit of amplitude from PSD:

Unit of $PSD= ((meter/second^2)^2/Hz)$ or $ 1.m^2.s^{-3}$, therefore, the unit of amplitude could be $ASD= ((meter/second^2)/√Hz)$ or  $ 1. m.s^{-3/2}$ which contradicts with the unit of amplitude $ A =(meter.second)^2/Hz$ provided in the question. In this case, this is amplitude spectral density $ASD$.

Comment: The factor of $2$ depends on whether you are using a one sided or two sided power spectrum (ie, whether or not you include negative frequencies). Otherwise the analysis on the DSP stack exchange you link to is correct.

Comment: @Andrew, Thanks for your comment. Could you please clarify the unit of the $ASD= ((meter/second^2)/√Hz)$?

Comment: Yes. If the time series has units of $m/s^2$, then the ASD has units of $(m/s^2)/\sqrt{Hz}$, the PSD has units of $(m/s^2)^2/Hz$, and the Fourier transform has units of $(m/s^2)/Hz$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got the unit of  "Amplitude " of Figure 3 in the link https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/ac348a/pdf is given $ Amplitude =((meter.second)^2/Hz) $. Once again, could you please clarify how do they find that unit or is there any typos? I cann't find the unit in that way.

Comment: Based on the units, that is a PSD. I think the authors are just being imprecise by using the word "amplitude" in the plot.

Comment: Good, you are very logical and I also expect something like that. If the unit is a $PSD=(quantity)^2/Hz$. So, I want to know what is the quantity that has a unit $ms=meter.second$

Answer (score -1):

This is what I figured out :

t : time (s)

a : acceleration (g)

L : number of time/acceleration samples

F : sampling frequency

1. Amplitude (g) = 2 * abs(FFT(a)) / L
2. PSD (g^2/Hz) = 2 * abs(FFT(a)) ** 2 / (F*L)
3. ASD (g/Sqrt(Hz)) = sqrt(PSD)
4. PSD or ASD in dB = 10*log(PSD or ASD)

Plot up to F/2.

Comment: So the unit of amplitude is not g/Hz but g. Moreover, the zero and Nyquist frequency should not be doubled.